# ASP.Net 3.5 ClientID Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple input element with `runat="server"`.  This field is nested in a couple of layers of user controls and I am pulling the ID with a getter but the ID given is not the full generated ID.

```
//UserControl2.ascx nested inside of UserControl1.ascx
...
<input type="text" runat="server" id="newTextBox" />
...

//UserControl1.ascx.cs nested inside of Page1.aspx
...
public string NewTextBoxId;
protected void UserControl2PlaceHolder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var c = LoadControl("~/Common/Controls/Shared/UserControl2.ascx");
    NewTextBoxId = ((App.Common.Controls.Shared.UserControl2) c).newTextBox.ClientID;
}
```

The issue is that NewTextBoxId is set to "newTextBox" instead of the fully generated "ct100_ct100_MainContent_etc._newTextBox".  The input's ID is rendered properly in the HTML but NewTextBoxId is not set properly.  To make matters a bit more odd, the input's ID is rendered as "newTextBox" on my local instance but when I deploy to our staging server, it is rendered as "ct100_ct100..._newTextBox" in the HTML.  Any ideas on this?

Comment: from what I remember LoadControl doesn't add 'c' to UserControl2's ControlCollection instance.  Have you tried getting the ClientId after it's added to the ControlCollection (which will initialize the control)?

Comment: @KenHenderson You, sir, are my hero.  I was pulling the ClientID before adding the control to the PlaceHolder.  Thank you, so much.  Go ahead and add that as an answer below and I will accept it.  :)

Comment: no problem.  Dynamic controls can be a little interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my comment.  The LoadedControl `c` has to be added to the ControlCollection of the current control prior to calling `c.ClientID`.  Adding to the ControlCollection will cause `c` to be initialized.

```
//UserControl2.ascx nested inside of UserControl1.ascx
...
<input type="text" runat="server" id="newTextBox" />
...

//UserControl1.ascx.cs nested inside of Page1.aspx
...
public string NewTextBoxId;
protected void UserControl2PlaceHolder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var c = LoadControl("~/Common/Controls/Shared/UserControl2.ascx");
    this.Controls.Add(c);
    NewTextBoxId = ((App.Common.Controls.Shared.UserControl2) c).newTextBox.ClientID;
}
```